# Inequality involving definite integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, integration

Just wondering, what may be the best way to show that $$\int_0^1 xf(x)dx \leq \frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)dx,$$ provided that $f(x) \geq 0$ over the interval $[0,1]$ and that $f(x)$ is monotonically decreasing?

Thanks!

Comment: Consider $\int_0^1 (\frac12 - x)f(x)\,dx$. Show that that is positive because $f$ is monotonically decreasing and non-negative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f$ and $x\mapsto x$ are of opposing monoticity, thus by [Chebyshev's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Integral_Chebyshev_inequality) for integrals:

$$\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx\leq \left(\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx\right)\left(\int_0^1 x\,dx\right)=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1 f(x)\,dx$$

---

If you are interested in a method without knowledge of the inequality, as suggested above:

$$\begin{aligned}\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)f(x)\,dx &=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)f(x)\,dx+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)f(x)\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} xf\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)\,dx-\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} xf\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}x\left[f\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)-f\left(\frac{1}{2}+x\right)\right]\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)\Big(f\left(x\right)-f\left(1-x\right)\Big)\,dx\geq 0\end{aligned}$$

(draw a sketch to see why the last inequality is true)

Comment: just what I need! Thanks pal!